# Visual Studio 2010 Debugger jumps around

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a simple C# Winforms application. It isn't multi-threaded (yet). When I debug it and step through the code at work, it debugs just as expected with the debug cursor moving line by line. But when I try doing this at my home computer, it behaves very erratic. The cursor will randomly jump to an unrelated line of code in the middle of another method that hasn't even been called yet etc.

The differences are:
At work I use VS2010 Professional, at home I have VS2010 Ultimate
At work, I use Win XP, at home I use Win 7 Ultimate
At work, its a dual core Athlon, at home a quad core Phenom II

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your symbols file might not match your source. Try deleteing your /bin folder and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: No problem, this is something I've run into as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the project configuration is set on `Debug` (not on `Release`!):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use other Projects too, make sure to go to ***Build => Batch Build*** and check if you build those other projects that you run as well

[image: Build => Batch Build]

I'm not sure which one will work for you but you should either *tick the Build option* or by *Modifying Solution Config* from Release to build,also you might need to delete your Bin Folder and Build from scratch.Then eiter click on build or do it from Solution Explorer. As shown you can Build other parts of the project and Debugger works rationally again.

[image: Batch Build]