# I'm debugging an application in Visual Studio 2010 going step by step and at one point it jumps to an unexpected part of the code. Is this a bug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm debugging an application in Visual Studio 2010 going step by step and, astonishingly, it jumps back to a part of code that doesn't suppose to, in a non linear manner. I run the code in a unit test, with debug (using resharper) and Visual Studio just stops, it doesn't say stackoverflow or anything after waiting for a while.

I think it is a bug. I happened at another time as well. Why would it jump code in such an arbitrary manner?

Do you know how to prevent this? Is some particular way of coding that makes this bug prone to happen?

Edit:
Part of the code where it jumps to:

```
foreach (var elemento in expresion.ElementosUsados)
        {
            valoresElementos.Add(new ValorYNombre(elemento.Nombre, elemento.GetValor(valoresBase)));
        }
```

at that time the value of "elemento" would be equal to "this" (a reference to the same object)

Comment: Is there any posibility of reentrancy, or are there multiple threads running through this code?

Comment: Are you sure an exception wasn't thrown?   Either that, or the use of the `yield` operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934073/visual-studio-2010-debugger-jumps-around

Comment: No, no multiple threads. I don't even know how to set up multiple threads. What do you mean by reentrancy?

Comment: @KirkWoll I'm going to let it for a long time to see if it eventually throws an exception.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're seeing this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you compiling with Optimization enabled? This can lead to code which will not perfectly mimic the flow of your written code but will mimic its functionality. This results in the debugger seemingly jumping from operation to operation.

---

EDIT <sub>by Olivier Jacot-Descombes</sub>:

[image]

<sub>I added the image here, since I cannot add it to a comment.</sub>

Comment: Yes, always debug in `Debug` mode, not in `Release` mode.

Comment: I don't know. Where do I set that option?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes how do I change the mode?

Comment: Optimization is disabled, if you are referring to Project > Properties > Build > Optimize code

Answer (score 5):

This could be possible when your application has multiple threads.

Comment: there will be a little blue mark on the yellow 'current line' mark if this is the case

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of reasons why the Visual Studio Debugger would suddenly jump in this manner.

1. You application has multiple threads.  At some point the context will switch between the threads and the debugger will jump accordingly to the newly active thread.  You can see if this is the case by opening the thread window and noting the active thread before and after the jump
2. An exception occurs in one of the sub functions.  Normally this would result in the exception dialog popping up but not always (it can be disabled).  You can do a more definitive check though by adding `$exception` to the watch window and seeing if it evaluates to a value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your build settings aren't correctly set up. This happens if you modify your file in one project, start debugging, but the changes were not compiled and the debugger uses an old version of the project. Now your code, with the new changes, and the assembly used by your debug process won't match. You can test this, by always rebuild your project, if the problem does not happen then, you need to set proper references to your assemblies, modify the build behavior of your targets or change the build order. Of course, if you only have one assembly, the application for example, this should not happen.
Besides that my guess is also multiple threads, optimized code, usage of [DebbugerStepThrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) or maybe it is as intended but you might not expect it.

For example:

```
myClass.Foo(something.Test);
```

if you step into this piece of code, you might expect to be in Foo, but `something.Test` must be called beforehand, thats why the compiler will jump to the getter of `Test`.

Maybe you provide 2 screenshots, before and after and we can have a better understanding what might be happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you *are* hitting a bug, the problem is likely due to some miscommunication between the JIT compiler & the debugger WRT sequence points.  I know we don't always get this right (I'm the dev lead for the JIT compiler :-).  **Can you post a little bit of code that's causing problems?**  One of the particularly problematic areas where I've seen this is around exception clauses.

Comment: I'm sorry, actually there _is_ something strange going on, I thought it was a stackoverflow because the code goes in circles (while debugging step by step), but at one point of the circuit, it jumps to a previous line. And I left it running for a long time and it doesn't throw stackoverflow. It's like it's reseting to a previous position. I'll post the code in a short time.